# ClickOnce : cannot download application

Tags: clickonce

I'm creating a clickonce POC. We like to use the deployment api to update, hence the application should not self-update the 'normal' way.

scenario 1:
check the 'application should check for updates' checkbox.

[image]

Publish
And try to install the application

Result : all works fine

scenario 2 :
uncheck the 'application should check for updates'
publish
try to install

ERROR

[image]

Details :

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO     Windows             : 10.0.16299.0 (Win32NT)    Common
>   Language Runtime  : 4.0.30319.42000   System.Deployment.dll       :
>   4.7.2556.0 built by: NET471REL1   clr.dll             : 4.7.2650.0 built by: NET471REL1LAST_B     dfdll.dll           : 4.7.2556.0 built by: NET471REL1
>     dfshim.dll          : 10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
>
> SOURCES   Deployment url          :
>   file:///C:/temp/ClickoncePOC.WPF%20(15).application
>
> IDENTITIES    Deployment Identity     : ClickoncePOC.WPF.application,
>   Version=1.0.1.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=664aa18d594fb70e,
>   processorArchitecture=msil
>
> APPLICATION SUMMARY   * Installable application.
>
> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
>   errors are listed later in the log.   * Activation of
>   C:\temp\ClickoncePOC.WPF (15).application resulted in exception.
>   Following failure messages were detected:         + Downloading
>   file:///C:/temp/Application
>   Files/ClickoncePOC.WPF_1_0_1_7/ClickoncePOC.WPF.exe.manifest did not
>   succeed.      + Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\Application
>   Files\ClickoncePOC.WPF_1_0_1_7\ClickoncePOC.WPF.exe.manifest'.        +
>   Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\Application
>   Files\ClickoncePOC.WPF_1_0_1_7\ClickoncePOC.WPF.exe.manifest'.        +
>   Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\Application
>   Files\ClickoncePOC.WPF_1_0_1_7\ClickoncePOC.WPF.exe.manifest'.
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY   No transaction error was
>   detected.
>
> WARNINGS  There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS     * [28/05/2018 11:41:56] : Activation of
>   C:\temp\ClickoncePOC.WPF (15).application has started.    * [28/05/2018
>   11:41:56] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully
>   completed.    * [28/05/2018 11:41:56] : Installation of the application
>   has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS     Following errors were detected during this operation.
>     * [28/05/2018 11:41:56]
>   System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown
>   subtype)
>         - Downloading file:///C:/temp/Application Files/ClickoncePOC.WPF_1_0_1_7/ClickoncePOC.WPF.exe.manifest did not
>   succeed.
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState
>   subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri&
>   sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification,
>   DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest
>   deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri,
>   IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri&
>   appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>   TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---          at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)        --- Inner Exception ---         System.Net.WebException
>         - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\Application Files\ClickoncePOC.WPF_1_0_1_7\ClickoncePOC.WPF.exe.manifest'.
>         - Source: System
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem
>   next)         --- Inner Exception ---         System.Net.WebException
>         - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\Application Files\ClickoncePOC.WPF_1_0_1_7\ClickoncePOC.WPF.exe.manifest'.
>         - Source: System
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)          at
>   System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)       ---
>   Inner Exception ---       System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
>         - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\temp\Application Files\ClickoncePOC.WPF_1_0_1_7\ClickoncePOC.WPF.exe.manifest'.
>         - Source: mscorlib
>         - Stack trace:          at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)          at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
>   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy,
>   Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)           at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)          at
>   System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length,
>   Boolean async)            at System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest
>   request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS   No transaction information is
>   available.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a workaround.

Deploy the app with update checked on.
Use mageui.exe to update the deploy manifest. In mageui uncheck updates, save and sign the manifest and you have a working version of the manifest.